# Prepositions for electronic devices

Tags: prepositions

Why do we say

> The file is **in** my computer.

but we say

> The file is **on** my phone.

or

> The file is **on** that iPad.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer your question, but for what it's worth, I *would* usually say "the file is on my computer." "In" might be appropriate in some contexts, but it sounds abnormal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your files **on** your computer, iPad, phone. But those files are **in** *My Documents* Folder or any other folder(s).

Comment: I see. It was because I heard the phrase "in the computer system" so often that caused the misunderstanding.